# Catch block is entered before "await Promise" is resolved

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, try-catch

Trying to save a camera snapshot in chrome. I have working code using Promise.resolve().then().catch() method, and I want to convert to async/await.

Original code:

```
function onSnapshotButtonClick() {
    imageCapture.takePhoto()
        .then(blob => createImageBitmap(blob))
        .then(imageBitmap => {
            drawCanvas(imageBitmap);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error("Snapshot failed."));
        console.log("Snapshot capture successful.");
})
```

New code:

```
var blob;
async function onSnapshotButtonClick() {
    // Take snapshot
    try {
        blob = await imageCapture.takePhoto();
        let imageBitmap = createImageBitmap(blob);
        drawCanvas(imageBitmap);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Snapshot failed.");
    }
    console.log("Snapshot successful.")

    // Do other stuff with blob...

})
```

But when running the above code, I get both "Snapshot failed." and "Snapshot successful." printed to the console and nothing gets drawn to the canvas (which a function defined later on). Why is the program entering the catch block, and shouldn't it exit the function when it does?

Edit: Thanks, I now understand that the catch block should include a return statement, and that I can learn more about the error by printing error.message. It seems like imageBitmap is not a valid format and that is causing the issue in the async/await version. The question remains then, since the original version doesn't have this issue, what is different in the async/await version that is causing this change in behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that your catch block doesn't have a `return` statement. So even if there is an error and it's caught, all it does is log your "Snapshot failed", and continue running the function. Try

```
try{
  ...
} catch(err){
    console.log("Snapshot failed: " + err)
    return;
}
//then do whatever it is you need if snapshot successful
```

As to why there is an error, try logging the actual err for better insight

Comment: Thanks for this insight. Turns out the error is happening because drawCanvas() is complaining about the type of imageBitmap. My question then is, since original code is able to draw the image, what is wrong in async/await version that is causing this?

Comment: So I'm not exactly sure how the drawCanvas(), createImageBitmap(), or image.takePhoto() functions work, but I'm guessing it's because createImageBitmap() might also be asynchronous? Try adding another `await` in front of it, as in `let imageBitmap = await createImageBitmap(blob);` and maybe see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you did not really understand how the `try/catch(/finally)` block works.

Basically, what you code does is (in pseudo code) :

```
Try this block :
    blob = await imageCapture.takePhoto();
    let imageBitmap = createImageBitmap(blob);
    drawCanvas(imageBitmap);
If any lines of the block above fails, then do this :
    console.error("Snapshot failed.");
After one of the 2 code blocks above are done, keep going

console.log("Snapshot successful.")
```

So your `try` block has an exceptions, goes to the `catch` block, then keep going.

If you want to do some processing of your image, do it in the `try` block, or `return` in the `catch` block.

[Here is some documentation on `try/catch(/finally)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Answer (score 0):

`catch` is not meant to *detect* errors, but to *handle* errors. Execution will continue as normal afterwards. You should log "Snapshot captured successful" inside the `try { ... }` or inside the last `.then(...)` respectively.

> Why is the program entering the catch block [at all] ?

Cause an error occured. You'll find out what the `error` is if you log it to the console.